# AJAX for rendering a partial or showing form errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, devise, partial

I am having difficulties in solving a form processing in an AJAX way with Rails.  I am going to try to explain the different parts I have, and where I do have doubts:

Here is how my **new.html.erb** looks like:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Enter Email' %>
  <%= f.submit "Step inside", :id => 'invitation_button' %>
<% end %>

<div id="request_invite">
</div>
```

As you can see, I have a `:remote => true`, so the submit is done via AJAX. Also, I have an empty container (#request_invite) which will be filled with a partial just in case the submit is successful.

Here is how my **registrations_controller.rb (create method)** looks like:

```
def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

My doubt is here.  What should I write in order to be able to let the JS know that the submission was successful or not.  If it was successful, I want to render a partial called `_thank_you.html.erb` into the #request_invite container.  If it was not successful, I want to show the errors in the form.

Here it comes my Javascript file that deals with the AJAX response:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("#new_user").on('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr)
  {
    alert("test");
  })
});
```

Right now the alert("test") always shows up as I don't have any way to know if there is a success or not.

Thanks a lot, I hope I explained myself well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you made a manual ajax call, with a success and failure callback on submission of the form (instead of using remote: true).  I'm tired, and not sure I'm following exactly what you're trying to do with your controller action.

```
  $('#form_name').submit (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax
      type: "POST"
      url: "/whatever_the_path_is"
      data: { 'email': $(@).val() }
      success: (result) ->
        $('#request_invite').html(result)
      failure: ->
        $('#request_invite').html("<h1>Request Failed</h1>")
```

And your controller might look like:

```
def create
      build_resource

      if resource.save
        if resource.active_for_authentication?
          sign_in(resource_name, resource)
          # respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
          render partial: '/partials_folder/thank_you'
        else
          expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
          # respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
          render partial: '/partials_folder/there_was_an_error'
        end
      else
        clean_up_passwords resource
        respond_with resource
      end
    end
```

Hopefully this gets you started on the right path.